# Python Selenium - iterate through search results

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In the search results, I need to verify that all of them must contain the search key. This is the HTML source code:

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Search Results</h1>
    <a id="main-content" tabindex="-1"></a>     
        <ul class="results">

                <li><img alt="Icon for Metropolitan trains" title="Metropolitan trains" src="themes/transport-site/images/jp/iconTrain.png" class="resultIcon"/> <strong>Stop</strong> <a href="/next5/diva/10001218/1">Sunshine Railway Station (Sunshine)</a></li>

                <li><img alt="Icon for Metropolitan trains" title="Metropolitan trains" src="themes/transport-site/images/jp/iconTrain.png" class="resultIcon"/> <strong>Stop</strong> <a href="/next5/diva/10001003/1">Albion Railway Station (Sunshine North)</a></li>                
        </ul>       
</div>
```

I have written this code to enter search key and get the results but it fails to loop through the search result:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/lovea/OneDrive/Documents/Semester 2 2016/ISYS1087/w3-4/chromedriver')

driver.get('http://www.ptv.vic.gov.au')

next5Element = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next 5 departures')
next5Element.click()

searchBox = driver.find_element_by_id('Form_ModeSearchForm_Search')
searchBox.click()
searchBox.clear()
searchBox.send_keys('Sunshine')

submitBtn = driver.find_element_by_id('Form_ModeSearchForm_action_doModeSearch')
submitBtn.click()

assert "Sorry, there were no results for your search." not in driver.page_source

results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='results']/li/a")
for result in results:
    assert "Sunshine" in result //Error: argument of type 'WebElement' is not iterable
```

Anyone please tell me what is the proper way to to that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if `innerHTML` value of particular element contains key string, but not element itself, so try

```
for result in results:
    assert "Sunshine" in result.text
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I got a mistake in `assert` statement.

Because `result` is a WebElement so there is no text to look up in it.

I just change it like: `assert "Sunshine" in result.text`